# Disable magento cache for page id

Tags: php, magento, caching

How can I disable the caching of:

```
Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getIdentifier()
```

I need to disable the cache for this because I want to show a static block only at the "home" page like:

```
<?php if (Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getIdentifier() == 'home' && Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getRouteName() == 'cms'): ?> 
<div>
  <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('shop-description-long')->toHtml() ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

At the moment magento caching this page id and I can see this block on every page.

Comment: you put static block in footer ?

Comment: have you tried disabling blocks cache from system cache management.

Comment: check this http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3124/how-can-i-disable-cache-for-particular-section-or-block

Comment: nope this block isn't in the footer and if I disabling blocks cache it works really fine, but the problem is the page id and not the block or am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found a solution:

Firstly I added the following to my local.xml:

```
<reference name="midcolumn">
   <block type="core/template" template="page/html/shop-description.phtml">
       <action method="setCacheLifetime"><s>null</s></action>
   </block>
</reference>
```

Then I created the file: shop-description.phtml with the following content:

```
<?php if (Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getIdentifier() == 'home' && Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getRouteName() == 'cms'): ?>
<section class="f-fix">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="headingBox"><h2><span>About the shop</span></h2></div>
        <div class="shop-description-long">
        <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('shop-description-long')->toHtml() ?>
        </div>
        <div class="shop-description-image">
        <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('shop-description-image')->toHtml() ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I don't know if it's a good solution for this problem, but it works. So any feedback would be nice :).

Answer (score 0):

Edit the "home" CMS page and put this in it's "Layout Update" field.

```
<reference name="content">
    <block type="cms/block" name="shop_description_long">
        <action method="setBlockId"><id>shop-description-long</id></action>
    </block>
</reference>
```

Comment: that's also possible, but so I had to push so much html into the cms block